# How to understand and solve stripe error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, pug, content-security-policy

In my `tour.pug` main head file this:

```
extends base
include _reviewCard
block append head
    script(src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.6.1/mapbox-gl.js")
    link(href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.6.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet')
    script(src='https://js.stripe.com/v3/')
```

In my `stripe.js` file:

```
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_something...')
```

When I load I get error:

> Refused to load the script 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/' because it
> violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://api.mapbox.com 'self' blob:".
> Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is
> used as a fallback.

After this I get mapbox error too:

> Refused to connect to 'ws://localhost:50364/' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'
> https://*.mapbox.com". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set,
> so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I didnt understand what mean these errors and how to fix these issues. Thanks

Comment: Both of the errors you mentioned are due to [the `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) being set by your web server.  Can you update your question with more details about the server/environment you're using and if you have control over that header/CSP configuration or not?  Currently there's not enough information to provide you with an answer.